# Find all $c\in\lbrace{0,1,2,3,...\rbrace}$ such that $n^2+cn$ is a perfect square for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I would like to determine all non-negative integers $c$ (i.e. $c\in\lbrace{0,1,2,3,...\rbrace}$) such that $n^2+cn$ is a perfect square for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How can I find all of them?

Best wishes

Comment: Do you have an example of such $c$ ?

Comment: Not that I don't like this kind of questions but apparently you're throwing contest questions without context or personal thoughts. That's not the spirit. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2720029/solving-the-functional-equation-fn2m-fnm2

Comment: @stity for what it's worth, $0$ is an example.

Comment: If we assume that we have such a $c \neq 0$, then we could plug in $n=1 \Rightarrow 1 + c$ has to be a square number. Therefore, $c$ has to be one less than a square number. Similarly, $n=2 \Rightarrow 4 + 2c$ has to be another square number ... Perhaps this kind of approach will give some insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is false unless $c = 0$, so that $n^2+cn = n^2$.  For $c > 0$, choosing $n = c$ gives $n^2+cn = 2c^2$, which is *never* a perfect square.

Answer (score 2):

$0$ is the only such number.

If not, let $c(\neq 0)$ be such a number and $p$ be a prime. Then, $p^2+cp=p(p+c)$ is a perfect square. Now, for this to be true, $p \mid (p+c) \implies p \mid c$. Since this is true for all $p$, $c$ is divisible by all primes, which evidently is not possible.